# Visualforce: Error on SOQL from Extension

Tags: apex, visualforce

I basically have standard controller and an apex extension. I need the standard controller to get the current record ID. Then in my extension i use that id to find other related records. When i try to pull these fields from the extra object i get this error: 'Invalid field Title for SObject EmailMessage'

```
<apex:page standardController="EmailMessage" extensions="EmailFilesApex" Action="{!RunSOQL}">
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ERecords}" var="Record">
       <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Account Title</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Title}"/>
       </apex:column>
       <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Id</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputText value="{!Record.Id}"/>
       </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:page>
```

//Class

```
public with sharing class EmailFilesApex {
public String currentRecordId {get;set;}
public String parameterValue {get;set;}
public Account acc{get;set;}
public List<ContentVersion> ERecords {get; set;}    

    public EmailFilesApex(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
    }

    public void RunSOQL(){
        ERecords = [SELECT Title, Id, FileType FROM ContentVersion WHERE FirstPublishLocationId =:currentRecordId];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name in apex:pageBlockTable var attribute is causing the issue. if you change it to any other name your code will be saved properly. I have changed **Record** to variable for example:-

```
<apex:page standardController="EmailMessage" extensions="EmailFilesApex">
    <apex:pageBlock title="My Content">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ERecords}" var="variable">
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Account Title</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!variable.Title}"/>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">Id</apex:facet>
                <apex:outputText value="{!variable.Id}"/>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:page>
```

Basically, When you are using StandardController, The below syntax are same:-

1. `{!Record.Title}`
2. `{!EmailMessage.Title}`

This is why, you were getting the **Invalid field Title for SObject EmailMessage** error because the there is no field with Title name on [EmailMessage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_emailmessage.htm) SObject.

Answer (score -1):

try this in constructor instead:

```
public EmailFilesApex(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {        
EmailMessage msg = (EmailMessage)controller.getRecord();
currentRecordId  = msg.id; }
```

Comment: hmm i seem to get: Incompatible types since an instance of Id is never an instance of EmailMessage

Comment: sorry just just do this:
EmailMessage msg = (EmailMessage)controller.getRecord();
currentRecordId  = msg.id;

Comment: That got rid of the incompatible type error but I'm still getting the Invalid field error on the VF side of things.

Comment: I don't think getting the record id is the problem here this bit works :)

Comment: This is a good example of why code dumps make poor answers. It didn't solve OP's problem, and with no explanation it led to a bunch of back-and-forth in the comments. Taking the time to explain _what_ the issue is, _how_ your solution works, and _why_ your solution works is important.